# Where/How to add "AddDefaultCharset utf-8" in httpd.conf

Tags: apache, utf-8, httpd.conf

After adding `AddDefaultCharset utf-8` into httpd.conf, wamp doesn't turn green and stays in orange. Although Port 80 is available.

Where/How to add `AddDefaultCharset utf-8` into httpd.conf exactly and properly? What should the syntax be?

Is it like adding `<IfModule mod_mime.c>AddDefaultCharset utf-8</IfModule>`
directly at the end of the file without space?
How can I handle those #'s?

Comment: Don't guess. Check the error logs for the exact problem.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I checked, but error logs don't say anything about why it doesn't turn green..

Answer (score 0):

The [AddDefaultCharset](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#adddefaultcharset) directive can be used where documentation explains:

> Description:  Default charset parameter to be added when a response content-type is text/plain or text/html
>   Syntax:   AddDefaultCharset On|Off|charset
>   Default:  AddDefaultCharset Off
>   Context:  **server config, virtual host, directory, .htaccess**
>   Override: FileInfo
>   Status:   Core
>   Module:   **core**

Also note it's a core directive so wrapping it in a `<IfModule mod_mime.c>` container doesn't make sense per-se.

Comment: I excluded `<IfModule mod_mime.c>`, I placed the directive only at the end of the file without container, so after some trial and error it turned green. Thank you @ÁlvaroGonzález